# Tesseract - OCR issues with typewriter style fonts

Tags: android, .net, ocr, tesseract

We are using Tesseract.NET (and the Android version too) to recognize and extract document data. It worked really good with Arial and Cambria fonts, but now we have to recognize documents like that:

[image]

Tesseract cannot recognize it. Absolutely nothing (except the big sized serial number on the right upper corner).

We tried to train it, but - maybe it's our fault - it's still unstable.

What can we do?

(Btw the font is use by national offices, we cannot get it as true type or other font format.

Answer (score 3):

In the current form it is very hard for an OCR tool to recognize any letters.

- Serif fonts are hard to ocr.
- Letters are very close together. Some are joined.
- A dictionary is not of any help.

You might be able to improve the result with the following:

- As this looks like an vehicle registration certificate you should be able to predict the positions of the textstrings of interest and then ocr they separatly.
- Thereby using the `-psm=7 or 8` option (assume single line or word).
- As some strings seem to be numbers only you can help tesseract by using the `digits` argument.
- For the alphanumeric strings it might help to reduce the dictionary pruning (or completely remove the dawg files.)
- If those strings like 'ETZ' or 'MZ' are abbreviations you could also build an dictionary with those.
- Reducing the yellow and green color is also an (easy) option you could test.
- Use the barcode instead of trying to ocr the string.

For tesseract questions it always helps if you specify the version used and, if you do image preprocessing, provide a sample image of the processed input.